# Store matrix from a text file in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, integer, text-files

Hello and great thanks in advance!!

I'm new in C++, sorry if my starting point is crap... I need to open and read a text file in order to apply some numerical procedures, but I'm finding it hard to figure this step out...

Next, you can see the text data. How would you read this text, storing those values/numbers in a matrix with dimension [3,4]?

readata.txt:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    1    0.00000e+00    0.00000e+00
    2    1.00000e+00    0.00000e+00
    3    0.00000e+00    -1.00000e+00
    4    2.00000e+00    -2.00000e+00
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

---

I'm stuck with this starting code...

```
string line;
ifstream myfile ("readata.txt");
if (myfile.is_open())
{
    while (! myfile.eof() )
{
for (int lineno = 0; getline (myfile,line) ; lineno++)
{
        if (lineno >= 2 && lineno <= 5)
        {
            cout << line << endl;
        }
        else
        {};
    }
    myfile.close();
}
else cout << "Unable to open file";
```

Comment: Use a [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) to process your line.

Comment: And dont use `while (! myfile.eof() )`

Comment: And please learn to indent your code. Writing unreadable code will only give you bad habits that will come back and haunt you in the (too soon) future.

Comment: (You're right Joachim.)
Can you give me some code directions so I can work it on? I already tried some things but can't put it to work...

Comment: Learn how to use a `std::stringstream`. Create a class that holds an integer and two doubles. Create an `std::vector` of that type, parse values from the stringstream into an instance of that class and `push_back()` that instance into the vector.

Comment: I suggest you read the input file as a string first then convert it later into int type, since you have some exponent values and negative values. You can try: ifstream readin(readata.txt); std::string st; int i = 0, j = 0; while(std::getline(readin, st)){if(j == 3) i++; else dimension[i][j++] = st;} Also remember to read in only numbers since ifstream will read everything including the characters "%". You need to add a delimiter to create an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get you started :

- Use [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) to manipulate a string (each line) as a stream
- Use [`std::stod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) to convert a `string` to `double`
- Do not check for `eof()`, it does not do what you think. instead, you can check the value returned by `getline()`

---

A minimal working example could look like this (it could be optimized but I hope it to be easy to read) :

```
int main()
{
    std::ifstream file("matrix.txt");

    if(!file)
        throw std::runtime_error("Error opening file");

    double matrix[4][3];
    std::string line;
    unsigned i = 0;
    while(std::getline(file, line))
    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << line;
        std::string x, y, z;
        ss >> x >> y >> z;

        double xd = std::stod(x);
        double yd = std::stod(y);
        double zd = std::stod(z);

        std::cout << xd << " " << yd << " " << zd << '\n';
        matrix[i][0] = xd;
        matrix[i][1] = yd;
        matrix[i][2] = zd;
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```